# aurelia-fetch-client - a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Response]

Tags: node.js, promise, aurelia, aurelia-fetch-client

I'm using the aurelia-fetch-client and I get this error when I send a request to my nodejs backend api:

```
Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Response]
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:39700:20
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at applyInterceptors (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:39696:33)
    at processResponse (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:39688:12)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:39603:18
From previous event:
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:39602:24
From previous event:
    at HttpClient.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:39590:64)
    at HttpClient.fetch (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:39574:23)
    at AuthService.login (http://localhost:9000/scripts/app-bundle.js:126:30)
    at Login.login (http://localhost:9000/scripts/app-bundle.js:190:30)
    at CallScope.evaluate (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:24067:21)
    at Listener.callSource (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:27508:42)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:27532:24
    at HTMLDocument.handleDelegatedEvent (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:25721:11)
```

Everything works fine but this warning is very annoying and I have no idea how to fix it, here's the code that sends the request:

```
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import baseConfig from 'config';

export class AuthService {
    constructor() {
        this.http = new HttpClient().configure(config => {
            config
                .withBaseUrl(baseConfig.baseUrl)
                .useStandardConfiguration();
        });

        this.isAuthenticated = false;
    }

    login(credentials) {
        return this.http.fetch('/login', {
            method: 'post',
            body: json(credentials)
        })
            .then(res => {
                this.saveToken(res.token)
                return Promise.resolve();
            });
    }

    saveToken(token) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: It's just a warning. Ignore it if you don't find it helpful.

Comment: The rejection seems to come from one of the (your?) interceptors. Please show us that code.

Comment: I did not write any interceptors, so can't be coming from one of mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aurelia-fetch-client standard configuration (applied in your code via `.useStandardConfiguration()`) rejects on non-success HTTP response status codes. There is a recent (closed) issue for this in the aurelia/fetch-client repo [here](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/issues/79). The fetch client is rejecting the promise with the response itself, and so the browser is complaining (it wants promises to only be rejected with instances of Error).

I addressed this in my own code by removing `.useStandardConfiguration()`, as I don't need it in this particular project. You can check out [the source code](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/blob/master/src/http-client-configuration.js) to get more of a picture of what's going on with the configuration.